# Verify that the web server is running and that incoming http request are not blocked by firewall

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i get a mvc project

this project bill success

but when run it show this error

> unable to start debugging on the web server .unable to connect to the web server . verify that the web server is running and that incoming http request are not blocked by firewall

thanks

Comment: I searched google with that exact error message and got this: http://celticcodingsolutions.com/Blog/post/2011/09/12/Unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server-(Visual-Studio-2010)-and-IIS-75-Part-2.aspx If this does not help, please explain why

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid tnks